# Backbone: fetch collection from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch a collection from my server.
I'm using version 0.3.3 (not the master from github)
However I am running in this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in {id=MyId, active=true}
    jQuery.jQuery.extend._Deferred.deferred.resolveWith (jquery.js:869)
    done (jquery.js:6591)
    jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

This is the way I created the error:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/collection',
    model: MyModel
});
var coll = new MyCollection();
coll.fetch();
```

The elements in /api/collection are parsed in JSON.
I tried to return them in various formats

```
["Id1", "Id2", ... ]
[{id: "Id1, somethingElse: "..."}, ...]
{id1: { id1s content}, id2: { ... }, ...}
```

However the error was always the same.
What is wrong with this code?

**[Edit]** It doesn't help to set an error via `coll.fetch({error: errorFunc});` The Exception stays the same.

**[Edit2]** Well it seems everything works fine until `collection.fetch()` calls `collection.refresh()` with the response object. I have not overwritten any of these functions.

**[Edit3]** The error is in the `collection.add()` method and the reason is that my elements are a list of strings... My server sent them wrong.

Comment: You say your server sent them wrong; how do you send 'em now so it works? Might be helpful for others (like me)

Comment: instead of ["id1", "id2", ..., "idn"] the client expects [{"id": "id1"}, ... {"id": "idn"}]

Comment: I'm literally echo-ing out '[{"id":"100"}]' from my server to test it out...however, it still gives the same error...what's the echo part of yours like?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

instead of

```
["id1", "id2", ..., "idn"]
```

the client expects

```
[{"id": "id1"}, ... {"id": "idn"}]
```

Comment: This thing always confuses me about JSON :(

What format should we choose. Not saying that JSON is bad, I might need to read up a bit

Comment: well, i am also stuck in same kind of problem. And in my situation the server is giving me json in format same as you have prescribed here... I still got the same error, can you help please... here is the error and data:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"UserId":1,"Login":"test","isSelected":true},{"UserId":2,"Login":"afdsafdsf","isSelected":true},{"UserId":61,"Login":"werewrewman","isSelected":false},{"UserId":62,"Login":"ghfgu","isSelected":false},.....]... will really appreciate your help.. thanks.

Comment: The reason the JSON needs to be in that format is because that's what Backbone has been designed to look for. Each Model has an `id` attribute [see the documentation for Model.id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id).

Backbone is trying to create a collection of models from an array of text strings - that won't work because a model is so much more than a single text string. But if you pass an array of objects with the `id` attribute set to a string, Backbone can extend each Model object with each respective object in the array, thus setting each Model's `id` to the text string.

Answer (score 23):

Since you already identified that your response format is not what Backbone expect, you should override **YourModel.parse** function that should take the response from your server and return an array of models acceptable by the collection. Here is the snippet from Backbone.js

```
// **parse** converts a response into a list of models to be added to the
// collection. The default implementation is just to pass it through.
parse : function(resp) {
  return resp;
},
```

As you can see the default function just passes data through. You would have to make it work for your response format.

P.S. id recommend placing a breakpoint in Backbone.fetch method to see what format comes from the server and where exactly it breaks the model creation.

Comment: Backbone expects a key "id" for each record (you can redefine the unique identifier key in your model by redeclaring idAttribute). Then the fetch from collection expects a [] json array.

Comment: Well, the "id" attribute is only used to determine whether or not the model is a new model or an existing one(meaning upon saving, do we need to create or update it?). The error that happens here, happens upon fetching the models from the server, so I beleive the problem is either bad response format that doesnt get parsed by JSON  into an object properly or its simply not in a format that Backbone expects and thus needs to be polished in the "parse" function